# Why is my CSS float not working properly? (width, height and float is defined in CSS)

Tags: css, css-float, html

Im trying to put 4 blocks in same line next to each other and I cant find my "error" in code so if anyone has got any idea why this is not working... Although in Dreamweaver floats are shown correctly, but when clicking Live view, they just fall one below the other. I've spent quite some time trying to find the answer here but I haven't found similar problem to mine so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:
CSS:

```
<style>
#stebr {width: 890px; height: 300px;margin-top: 50px;}
#stebr .pic { width: 195px; height: 150px; background:url(img/s1.png) no-repeat; }
#stebr .pic2 { width: 195px; height: 150px; background:url(img/s2.png) no-repeat; }
#stebr .pic3{ width: 195px; height: 150px; background:url(img/s3.png) no-repeat; }

#stebr .naslov h1 { width:195px; height: 25px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; color:#ff4e00; margin-top:15px; background-image:url(img/line.png); background-position:bottom; background-repeat:no-repeat; }
#stebr .tekst p { width:195px; height: 80px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color:#CCC; }

#stebr .1 {width: 195px; height: 290px; float:left; }
#stebr .2 {width: 195px; height: 290px; float: left;}
#stebr .3 {width: 195px; height: 290px; float: right; }
#stebr .4 {width: 195px; height: 290px; float: right; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="stebr">
<div class="1">
<div class="pic"></div>
<div class="naslov"><h1>Who are they?</h1></div>
<div class="tekst"><p>Hello world</p></div>
</div>
<div class="2">
<div class="pic2"></div>
<div class="naslov"><h1>What they do</h1></div>
<div class="tekst"><p>Hello world</p></div>
</div>
<div class="3">
</div>
<div class="4"><div class="pic3"></div>
<div class="naslov"><h1>Where are we</h1></div>
<div class="tekst"><p>Hello world</p></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: "Although in Dreamweaver floats are shown correctly, but when clicking Live view" — I've never heard anything good about Dreamweaver's WYSIWYG view, and none of your visitors are going to be using it as a client. Test in web browsers, not editors.

Comment: thank you for the answer, same problem in browsers. And what you suggest is better to use than Dreamweaver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css class names starting with numbers are not allowed, you have to rename it. Simple rename it to .c1 .c2 etc and it will work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="stebr">
    <div class="c1">
        <div class="pic"></div>
        <div class="naslov">
            <h1>Who are they?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tekst">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="pic2"></div>
        <div class="naslov">
            <h1>What they do</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tekst">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c3"></div>
    <div class="c4">
        <div class="pic3"></div>
        <div class="naslov">
            <h1>Where are we</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tekst">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#stebr {
    width: 890px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#stebr .pic {
    width: 195px;
    height: 150px;
    background:url(img/s1.png) no-repeat;
}
#stebr .pic2 {
    width: 195px;
    height: 150px;
    background:url(img/s2.png) no-repeat;
}
#stebr .pic3 {
    width: 195px;
    height: 150px;
    background:url(img/s3.png) no-repeat;
}
#stebr .naslov h1 {
    width:195px;
    height: 25px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color:#ff4e00;
    margin-top:15px;
    background-image:url(img/line.png);
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#stebr .tekst p {
    width:195px;
    height: 80px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#CCC;
}
#stebr .c1 {
    width: 195px;
    height: 290px;
    float:left;
}
#stebr .c2 {
    width: 195px;
    height: 290px;
    float: left;
}
#stebr .c3 {
    width: 195px;
    height: 290px;
    float: right;
}
#stebr .c4 {
    width: 195px;
    height: 290px;
    float: right;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj99w/

Comment: You just saved me about 2 years of my life.. Thank you very much, and I F$#%=)&# knew it it has to be some kind of stupid mistake of mine.. Thanks again! :)

Comment: You're welcome, please dont forget to mark the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your [CSS in invalid](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input). You cannot start a class selector with a number.